# Disabling some options in a filter using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created this table just for example.
[image]

I need the value **(Blanks)** not to be selectable in the filter so that I can only select 4 in column B and only 2 in column C.
[image]

I tried to make a simple example. The original table is much bigger. It is specifically about this macro used to hide/show empty columns when changing the filter, which when selected **(Blanks)** two problems will occur.

1. Will only show columns that contain something on the last line (see printscreen below). But why this happens and only sometimes, I really don't know.
2. More importantly the given column where I chose **(Blanks)** will be hidden, which is obviously wrong, because otherwise I can't undo it and I have to unhide all the columns manually to be able to do it.
   I would like to modify the macro so that it ignores the column in which I have selected **(Blanks)**.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns("A:AK").Hidden = False
For i = 1 To 1000
    If Application.Subtotal(103, Columns(i)) = 1 Then Columns(i).Hidden = True
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any way in VBA to do that.  You'd need to create your own filter drop-downs.

Comment: Do you really need to disable the (Blanks) option of the filter, which looks fancy, or using a piece of code able to filter on the two columns/values?

Comment: @TimWilliams I can. However, is it possible to create a custom drop-down that will also work as a filter?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes, I want. I need to solve a problem with a macro I already have there (I added it to the end of the question itself)

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... Why don't to **uncheck the respective option**, if you manually filter the range? Is it something else I am missing?

Comment: @FaneDuru Sorry, I still edited the question. I primarily need to fix the macro to not hide the column where I chose Blanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not perfect to meet OP's expectation. But it is close.

***Note***: users have to select the cell first before clicking dropdown button.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 And .Row = 1 And Len(.Cells(1)) > 0 Then
            Dim rCell As Range, arr, i As Long
            arr = Me.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value
            For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
                If arr(i, .Column) = "" Then
                    If rCell Is Nothing Then
                        Set rCell = Me.Cells(i, 1)
                    Else
                        Set rCell = Union(rCell, Me.Cells(i, 1))
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If Not rCell Is Nothing Then rCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I have tested `arr = Me.[a1].CurrentRegion.Value for a discontinuous (filtered) range` w/o any issue on Excel 365. It gets the whole data range. If lower version Excel has the problem, `Usedrange` is an option.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Even if the range is filtered, `Me.[a1].CurrentRegion` includes all the range, not only the visible rows. I will delete my above comment.

Comment: I'm lost. Do you want to hide the column(s) or not? If yes, what's kind of cloumn(s)?

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome I take back my original answer. I want the columns to be hidden because they don't really contain anything and not the column itself to be hidden because I chose blanks there.